# What type of server is necessary for video streaming and Data Storage?

Tags: database, server, video-streaming, live-streaming

Good Day,

I apologize for the inconvenience but I would like some help.

I am tasked with setting up a Data center which is capable of storing large amounts of Data and have the capability to handle 1080p live streaming, I have figured out most of the storage server requirements but the video streaming requirements just baffle me. I have no experience when it comes to video streaming.

Can I use the same server for Data Storage in Video Streaming? if not, what can you guys recommend?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Awad

Comment: Not a system architect, but you'll need a file-system that can handle large files fast and a lot of sequential read (multiple, concurrent). There are also the bandwidth requirements but that's something else.